# Error - Attempted to load interface "SessionInterface" while trying to enter Categories in admin panel Prestashop 1.7.6.5

Tags: php, symfony, prestashop-1.7

I have made many changes in my Prestashop and don't know when my problem appeared.
So when I try to enter categories or invoices in back office I get error like on image and text below.

> Attempted to load interface "SessionInterface" from namespace
> "PrestaShop\PrestaShop\Core\Session". Did you forget a "use" statement
> for e.g. "Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\SessionInterface"
> or "PrestaShop\PrestaShop\Core\Session\SessionInterface"?

[error view 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b9Asf.png)
[error view 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5gTQQ.png)

Does anybody know what can cause that and what is solution for this?
Really appreciate any help

Thank you in advance

Comment: So the solution for the problem was just to rename the file from CustomerSession.php to (for example in my case) CustomerSession_copy.php and everything works now. Thank everyone for help

Answer (score 0):

Your error is pointing to the file "[/classes/CustomerSession.php](https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/blob/develop/classes/CustomerSession.php)" However the error pointed is not an issue with this file. Your error might be a cache issue. Try to delete

`/yourstore/var/cache/dev` and `/yourstore/var/cache/prod`

Answer (score -1):

Try to update to version 1.7.7.*
I found that file in this version:
https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/blob/1.7.7.x/src/Core/Session/SessionInterface.php

Comment: I will try but shouldn't it be not necessary to update if it worked earlier?

Comment: It could be a version bug, that fixed in a new version